# what's the difference between val and const val in companion object?

Tags: android

When I write static final variable in companion object{}, I have two options.
The one is just using val, and the other is const val.
When I decompile the two variable, the only difference is
val is private, but const val is public.
So is there no problem whatever I choose?

*koltin file*

```
class Test {
    companion object{
        val test = 5
        const val test2 =5
    }
}
```

*decompiled file*

```
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 4, 2},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0003\u0018\u0000 \u00032\u00020\u0001:\u0001\u0003B\u0005¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002¨\u0006\u0004"},
   d2 = {"Lcom/jakchang/emo/data/network/emo/Test;", "", "()V", "Companion", "EMOPlayer.app"}
)
public final class Test {
   private static final int test = 5;
   public static final int test2 = 5;
   @NotNull
   public static final Test.Companion Companion = new Test.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker)null);

   @Metadata(
      mv = {1, 4, 2},
      bv = {1, 0, 3},
      k = 1,
      d1 = {"\u0000\u0014\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\b\n\u0002\b\u0004\b\u0086\u0003\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0007\b\u0002¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002R\u0014\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004X\u0086D¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0005\u0010\u0006R\u000e\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\u0004X\u0086T¢\u0006\u0002\n\u0000¨\u0006\b"},
      d2 = {"Lcom/jakchang/emo/data/network/emo/Test$Companion;", "", "()V", "test", "", "getTest", "()I", "test2", "EMOPlayer.app"}
   )
   public static final class Companion {
      public final int getTest() {
         return Test.test;
      }

      private Companion() {
      }

      // $FF: synthetic method
      public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
         this();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const val` - it's a compilation time variable. It should be determined at the compilation step.

in case with `val`, it can be assigned in runtime.
just an example:

```
companion object{

    const val fooConst = someCalculation()   //Not possible, only primitives and String are allowed.
    val fooVal = someCalculation()  // possible
    
}
```

Constants in Kotlin language reference:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#compile-time-constants

Comment: I've edited answer, but it's just an example, to explain the difference.